# Call 'sudo make install' from gvim

Tags: vim, makefile, installation, sudo

I am developing a program which has a fairly standard looking Makefile like the one below.

```
.PHONY=default install

hello: hello.o

install: hello
    cp hello /usr/local/bin
```

This example Makefile builds a program called `hello` from a file called `hello.c` and has an installation rule to install it to a directory which is owned by root. This means that the install must be called with the `sudo` command like so:

```
sudo make install
```

Now I use gvim as a text editor and use the `:make` command all the time to make it. I would also like to be able to install it from the vim command, but I cannot figure out how to insert the `sudo` command into the `:make` command.

There is a workaround that I can do which is to put the `sudo` in the Makefile rule itself, but I feel like this is bad practice.

Does anyone know how to run a single command from within vim with elevated privileges?

Comment: Open the editor with sudo command, :make would work.

Comment: This is a  "bad idea". See http://superuser.com/questions/23428/vim-sudo-vim-bad-idea. Besides, it would also make the local output belong to root high is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be just have vim run an external command with `!`

```
:!sudo make install
```

Take a look at `:help :!`

Comment: Funny that I knew about `:make` but not about `:!`. You are absolutely right!